# Change linear string replace operations to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'd like to change the following code into an array because whenever I want to add a new string to be replaced, I have to write `"roman_ok"+number`. This is not convenient if you have a few hundred strings to add. Could someone tell how to do it?

```
function roman_conversion(format) {
    var roman_ok = format.replace(/./gm, convert_text);
    var roman_ok2 = roman_ok.replace(/l%r/g, "ll");
    var roman_ok3 = roman_ok2.replace(/l%n/g, "ll");
    var roman_ok4 = roman_ok3.replace(/nr/g, "ll");
    var roman_ok5 = roman_ok4.replace(/l%y/g, "ry");
    var roman_ok6 = roman_ok5.replace(/l%w/g, "rw");
    var roman_ok7 = roman_ok6.replace(/kn/g, "ngn");
    var roman_ok8 = roman_ok7.replace(/kr/g, "ngn");
    var roman_ok9 = roman_ok8.replace(/km/g, "ngm");
    var roman_ok10 = roman_ok9.replace(/tn/g, "nn");
    var roman_ok11 = roman_ok10.replace(/tr/g, "nn");
    var roman_ok12 = roman_ok11.replace(/tm/g, "nm");
    var roman_ok13 = roman_ok12.replace(/mr/g, "mn");
    var roman_ok14 = roman_ok13.replace(/pn/g, "mn");
    var roman_ok15 = roman_ok14.replace(/pr/g, "mn");
    var roman_ok16 = roman_ok15.replace(/pm/g, "mm");
    var roman_ok17 = roman_ok16.replace(/ngr/g, "ngn"); 
    return roman_ok17;
```

Comment: Where does `convert_text` come from?

Comment: that's a function I didn't quote in this message (I don't think it should be important here) ; it's a first conversion of single characters to the ones I'm trying to replace here

Comment: got some test data?

Comment: Yes, given an array containing regex replacements, you can use the `reduce` method to apply all of them to your input.

Comment: It's difficult to test an answer with no data and no real understanding of how this funciton is to be used.  You're replacing everything in the only parameter with something that comes from who knows where.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use those intermediate variables. You could just chain the `replace` calls: `return format.replace(/aa/, 'bb').replace(/cc/, 'dd').replace ............ ;` Be aware also that a replacement may produce something that is again replaced by one of the following replacements. Knowing the exact case would help to identify maybe better ways to approach this.

Comment: thank you, this was the easiest way to get it done quickly (I'm aware of the consequences of the replace method) !

Comment: @Aakash: Some of your recent edits have been rejected. Please do not make everything `code` that *sounds* like `code`, such as `array` and `string`. Formatting something as `code` should only be used for actual `code`, not for everything else `computer` related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer in my case was the one of Trincot inside the comments:

> Note that you don't have to use those intermediate variables. You could just chain the replace calls:
>
> ```
> return format.replace(/aa/, 'bb').replace(/cc/, 'dd').replace ............ ;
> ```
>
> Be aware also that a replacement may produce something that is again replaced by one of the following replacements. Knowing the exact case would help to identify maybe better ways to approach this.
> – trincot Aug 14 at 6:50

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```
var replacements = [[/foo/, 'bar'], [/baz/, 'quux'], ...];
function roman_conversion(format) {
    return replacements.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.replace(curr[0], curr[1]), format);
}
```

EDIT: Using ES6 arrow function syntax here, feel free to replace with `function(prev, curr) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you wanted

```
function Replacement(pattern, replacement) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.replacement = replacement;
}

var replacements = [
    //  new Replacement(new RegExp('.', 'gm'), convert_text), 
    new Replacement(new RegExp("l%r", "g"), "ll"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("l%n", "g"), "ll"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("nr", "g"), "ll"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("l%y", "g"), "ry"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("l%w", "g"), "rw"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("kn", "g"), "ngn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("kr", "g"), "ngn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("km", "g"), "ngm"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("tn", "g"), "nn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("tr", "g"), "nn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("tm", "g"), "nm"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("mr", "g"), "mn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("pn", "g"), "mn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("pr", "g"), "mn"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("pm", "g"), "mm"),
    new Replacement(new RegExp("ngr", "g"), "ngn"),
];

function roman_conversion(string) {
    return replacements.reduce(
        function(previous, current) {
            return previous.replace(current.pattern, current.replacement);
        }, string);
}
```